# Multiplying combinations across rows in different arrays in Python

Tags: python

Say I have a list, A.shape = (5, 20) and another, different list, B.shape = (5, 20). I want to find and store all combinations of row multiplications.

I.e. `A[1,:]*B[1,:],  A[1,:]*B[2,:],  ...  A[5,:]*B[5,:]`

The trouble I'm having is how to isolate rows in list combinations. What I have so far, if I was considering combinations of elements within lists is:

```
[ x*y for x in A for y in B]
```

which does not work for row-wise multiplication. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: looks like you want `np.outer(A, B)`?

Comment: This does seem to work for two arrays quite well, thanks. I'm not too familiar with the output, and the documentation does not seem to clarify this too well, but is there a way to simply have the output be the different combined rows? As is this seems to give me a matrix with many repeats

Comment: I'm having trouble visualising your problem without some example input and output, help me out here?

Comment: Of course. Say I have an A = np.array([1,1,1], [2,2,2]) and a B = np.array([3,5,8], [9,9,2]). The output I would ideally want would be: C = [[3,5,8], [9,9,2], [6,10,16], [18,18,4]], where each row in the output corresponds to one of the combinations. np.outer gives me all the combinations but in a form that I can't easily change to suit the desired output, for a generalised case.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Looks like you just want this: `(B * A[:, None]).reshape(-1, 3)`

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks! If I wanted to extend this further to N arrays instead of just two is there a simple way to accomplish this that doesn't involve looping over multiple of these storing the resultant array every time?

Comment: Not sure, you may check out options with `np.multiply.reduce`...